# How can I use the post ID instead of slug in the permalinks of just one of my wordpress custom post types?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, permalinks

I have a wordpress website with a custom post type "intake".

Intakes are only sets of dates (via custom fields) so they don't have a semantically useful title. In fact, I've disabled the title editor completely in this post type.

Rather than the default permalinks Wordpress gives me, which look something like these:

```
/intake/auto-draft
?intake=auto-draft-2
```

I'd instead like to change the prefix and use the ID:

```
/apply/12345
```

But I'm running into trouble.

I don't want to change my global permalink settings because they work great for the other post types on my site.

So far I've tried:

- Using the rewrite options in the args of `register_post_type()`. I can change "intake" to "apply" there but no luck replacing the post name with the ID.
- Using `add_rewrite_rule()` to accept my desired permalink format, which works, but Wordpress redirects me to an ugly URL like: `?intake=auto-draft-2`. Terrible!

Here are those attempts:

```
    register_post_type("intake", array(
        "label" => __("Intakes"),
        "supports" => false,
        "rewrite" => array(
            "slug" => "apply"
        )
    ));
```

```
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'apply/([^/]*)/?',
        'index.php?p=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
```

Another solution could be to use permastructs? But I'm struggling to wrap my head around that.

---

Could simply changing the slug to be the ID be a more robust solution?

```
function lbh_custom_intake_slug( $slug, $post_id, $post_status, $post_type, $post_parent, $original_slug ) { 
    if($post_type === "intake"){
        return $post_id;
    }
    return $slug; 
};
add_filter( 'wp_unique_post_slug', 'lbh_custom_intake_slug', 10, 6 );
```

Comment: Would it be an option to simply change the slug to match the ID when you create the CPT posts? That would let you use the default WP behaviour and avoid all the playing around with permalinks & rewrite rules and all the associated pitfalls :)

Comment: Sounds good to me! Not sure what that would involve though, I did a quick search for a way to filter slugs based on post type but no luck!

Comment: Check out `wp_unique_post_slug()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_unique_post_slug/

Comment: For new posts, you just need to hook into the `save_post` action for your CPT to set the title when it is being saved. To change the existing ones, if there aren't too many, you can do it manually in the WP post editor. If that's not an option then you could do it through PHP, you'd probably query all your CPT posts and loop through that to update post details for each.